# How extract this firmware file?

Tags: firmware

I need extract this firmware file. I tried `firmwaremodkit` and `binwalk`. It founds two trx headers, but cannot open it.( delete start in hexedit and untrx throws segfault, fmk found nothing)...

Interesting is the constant repetition of the sequence: 00 00 11 53 48 44 52

Some tips how extract it?

http://uloz.to/xY4X3cPh/download-dwn

Comment: Have you searched on this site for answers? Because I remember at least two or three *very* similar questions.

Comment: The repeating sequence appears to be `5[id] 00 length`, where *id* somehow indicates how *length* must be interpreted. For the `SHDR` blocks it's always `11`, all next blocks say `0480`, which is *might* mean "4 * 0x8000" but appear to be 0x2001C bytes long. The last 4 bytes of each block look like a CRC.

Comment: Yes, I searched, there are similar questions, but without a functioning solution for me...(for example this is very similar http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/how-to-unpack-a-tftp-file-with-firmware?rq=1) but it is for different box... My file is for update over usb...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an encrypted firmware of the GBR2851T Freeview HD Digital Receiver, so you cannot extract it without the proper encryption key.
If you are interested in i-CAN (ADB) internals, see the following vulnerability report http://www.security-explorations.com/materials/se-2011-01-adb.pdf.